# CSS: Website looks okay on reducing browser width, but cuts in half on phone screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my [website](http://www.sanchayjaveria.com/), If you view this in the browser and decrease the browser width, it'll look fine. 
However, if you look at it in your actual mobile device (I tested it on my iPhone) it'll be cut in half. I have no clue why this is happening. I've played around with a lot of meta tags as well. Currently I have this,
 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`
I've tried doing this too,
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`
But this makes my website horizontally scrollable up to double the actual width. (it just shows whitespace). 
I also have,

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

in my media queries, I have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set your meta tag to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1">`

Then, your `header .main-headline` is having 950 width that causes the problem.

Comment: I see `width: 1140px` where do you see `950px`?

Comment: Maybe I modified some css with the debugger but you got the point, .main-headline and it's child having width that exceeded the screen width

Comment: Thank you to both of you for responding so quickly. Since you answered first I'm marking your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with `<div class="main-headline"></div>` it have fixed width `width: 1140px;` and huge `margin-left: 150px;` and `padding-left: 190px;` use just `padding` for your case.

Answer (score 0):

The element div with class ".main-headline", has a fixed width of 1140px, that creates that space on the left, try to reduce it or use a max-width: 100% in the media queries.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I forgot to restrict the width while writing my media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding:

```
<body width=100%>
```

or

```
<div width=100%>
```

On Safari you can too check what your website would look like on other devices and iPads by going to Develop > Enter Responsive Design Mode (make sure 'Develop' is enabled in Advanced Settings in Safari Pref).

Answer (score -1):

**.main-headline** in this class margin-left remove because you use width 100% with margin.